# How do I calculate cross-entropy from probabilities in PyTorch?

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, loss-function, cross-entropy

By default, PyTorch's `cross_entropy` takes logits (the raw outputs from the model) as the input. I know that `CrossEntropyLoss` combines `LogSoftmax` (log(softmax(x))) and `NLLLoss` (negative log likelihood loss) in one single class. So, I think I can use `NLLLoss` to get cross-entropy loss from probabilities as follows:

> true labels: [1, 0, 1]
>   probabilites: [0.1, 0.9], [0.9, 0.1], [0.2, 0.8]

[image]

where, `y_i,j` denotes the true value i.e. 1 if sample `i` belongs to class `j` and 0 otherwise.
and `p_i,j` denotes the probability predicted by your model of sample `i` belonging to class `j`.

If I calculate by hand, it turns out to be:

```
>>> -(math.log(0.9) + math.log(0.9) + math.log(0.8))
0.4338
```

Using PyTorch:

```
>>> labels = torch.tensor([1, 0, 1], dtype=torch.long)
>>> probs = torch.tensor([[0.1, 0.9], [0.9, 0.1], [0.2, 0.8]], dtype=torch.float)
>>> F.nll_loss(torch.log(probs), labels)
tensor(0.1446)
```

What am I doing wrong? Why is the answer different?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a reduction parameter for all loss functions in the PyTorch. As you can see from the [documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.functional.html?highlight=nll%20loss#torch.nn.functional.nll_loss) default reduction parameter is 'mean' which divides the sum with number of elements in the batch. To get  a summation behavior (0.4338) as you want, you should give the reduction parameter as following:

```
F.nll_loss(torch.log(probs), labels,reduction='sum')
```